# Python: Compare distance between entries in a list and replace an entry if the distance is less than a specific number?

Tags: python, combinations, distance, python-itertools

I have generated a random list as follows, where each entry corresponds to x,y,z coordinates. I then compare the distance between each entry as follows:

```
myList = []
for x in range(12): #12 is just an example number, just a multiple of 3
    myList.append(random.uniform(0,1))
#Split list into x,y,z coordinates
n = 3
newList = [myList[i:i + n] for i in xrange(0, len(myList), n)]

#function to get distance
def distance(p1, p2):
    myDist = math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2 + (p1[2] - p2[2])**2)
    return myDist

#Compare distance between each entry in newList
for a,b in itertools.combinations(newList, 2):
    distance(a,b)
```

My question is:

If distance(a,b) < **i, where i is some number**, I want to replace a and/or b with a new entry such that the distance is greater than i. In the end, I want a list such that the distance between any two points are all greater than i. I was thinking of adding an if statement here:

```
#Compare distance between each entry in newList
i = 0.4 #can be any number
for a,b in itertools.combinations(newList, 2):
    distance(a,b)
    if distance(a,b) < i:
        #replace a and/or b
```

However, then I think I would need to iterate over newList again to make sure none of the new points generated are within i distance of the other points, and keep doing this until all the points are greater than i distance apart. Is there a neat way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The order of iteration will affect your final answer. Is this intended?

Comment: Well my final goal would be to end up with a bunch of entries/points where none of the points are less than i distance apart. Would order still affect things here?

Answer (score 0):

> However, then I think I would need to iterate over newList again to make sure none of the new points generated are within i distance of the other points, and keep doing this until all the points are greater than i distance apart. Is there a neat way to do this? Thanks!

There are neater ways to do this, but they would all involve using a balanced tree structure to perform 2-d collision detection faster than checking every point, so that checking if a new point is valid only takes log(n) time instead of n.

You can avoid generating a full original list; it is slightly faster to generate points one at a time, validate them, and then add them to the (initially empty) list.

Comment: I see - so it seems like it would be better to then generate points one at a time, check the distance of this new point with all the previous points, and then add it to the list if the distance is greater than i. The goal would be to end up with a bunch of entries/points where none of the points are less than i distance apart.